# Can npm library use standalone components?

Tags: angular, npm-package, angular15

I'm using standalone components in my Angular 15 app, and I'm realizing that 4-5 of them are going to be useful across projects, so I considered moving them into an npm library. Everything I know about libraries though is that they're done via modules.  Is there something special that needs to be done for standalone, or is it just "You don't use standalone in a library"?

I tried to just put the standalone components there without any module file, and then I exported the components.  It compiles file, but when I run I get a ton of errors saying:

> G0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`.

Those errors don't exist before pulling the components out.

In my library component I've done this:

```js
export const PERSON_DEFAULT_OPTIONS = new InjectionToken<IPersonDefaults>('Graph Toolkit person defaults')

export interface IPersonDefault { ... }

@Component({...})
export class PersonComponent {
    readonly #config = inject(PERSON_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, {optional: true})
}
```

That seems to be what's triggering the error.  I also tried the "old" syntax:

```js
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(PERSON_DEFAULT_OPTIONS) ...
```

The app that calls the library provides that token in `main.ts`

Comment: This is thoroughly covered in the docs https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries Is there something not covered there that you still have a question about?

Comment: @MarkClark I don't see anything in the angular guide related to standalone components in a library.

Comment: I believe standalone components in libraries aren't different from the ones in application. could you provide a piece of code where `inject()` is used inside of a component?

Comment: @Andrei I added to the question description.

Comment: What is standalone component????

Comment: @Antoniossss Was introduced in NG14 and omits the writing of an angular module

Comment: According to [this link](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#using-standalone-components-in-ngmodule-based-applications) all should be possible and the system is designed to incrementally migrate from `NgModule` applications to standalone module applications seamlessly. So I guess combining both principles should be possible, and thus libraries of both kinds should be able to be used in applications of both kinds

Comment: hm, and could you please also add a piece of code where this component gets to the application? is it just imported into some module's imports? or maybe rendered dynamically?

Comment: @Andrei There are no modules.  It's just put into the import of the app's `@Component{}` specifier.